# RGB -> XYZ conversion doesn't work right

Tags: c#, colors, color-space

I got a XYZ to RGB converter from [here](http://www.easyrgb.com/index.php?X=MATH) and wrote it into C# but, I've been having some problems.

```
public static XYZColor RGBtoXYZ(RGBColor rgb)
    {
        XYZColor xyz = new XYZColor();

        float r, g, b;
        r = rgb.R;
        g = rgb.G;
        b = rgb.B;


        if (r > 0.04045f) r = (float)Math.Pow((r + 0.055)/1.055, 2.4);
        else r = r / 12.92f;
        if (g > 0.04045) g =(float)Math.Pow((g + 0.055f)/1.055f , 2.4f);
        else g = g/12.92f;
        if (b > 0.04045f) b = (float)Math.Pow((b + 0.055f)/1.055f , 2.4f);
        else b = b/12.92f;

        r *= 100;
        g *= 100;
        b *= 100;

        xyz.X = r*0.4124f + g*0.3576f + b*0.1805f;
        xyz.Y = r*0.2126f + g*0.7152f + b*0.0722f;
        xyz.Z = r*0.0193f + g*0.1192f + b*0.9505f;

        xyz.A = rgb.A;
        return xyz;
    }

    public static RGBColor XYZtoRGB(XYZColor xyz)
    {
        RGBColor rgb = new RGBColor();

        float x, y, z;
        x = xyz.X;
        y = xyz.Y;
        z = xyz.Z;

        x = x/100;        //X from 0 to  95.047      (Observer = 2°, Illuminant = D65)
        y = y/100;        //Y from 0 to 100.000
        z = z/100;     //Z from 0 to 108.883

        rgb.R = x*3.2406f + y*-1.5372f + z*-0.4986f;
        rgb.G = x*-0.9689f + y*1.8758f + z*0.0415f;
        rgb.B = x*0.0557f + y*-0.2040f + z*1.0570f;

        if (rgb.R > 0.0031308f) rgb.R = 1.055f*(float)Math.Pow(rgb.R, (1/2.4f)) - 0.055f;
        else rgb.R = 12.92f*rgb.R;
        if (rgb.G > 0.0031308f) rgb.G = 1.055f*(float)Math.Pow(rgb.G ,(1/2.4f)) - 0.055f;
        else rgb.G = 12.92f*rgb.G;
        if (rgb.B > 0.0031308f) rgb.B = 1.055f*(float)Math.Pow(rgb.B, (1/2.4f)) - 0.055f;
        else rgb.B = 12.92f*rgb.B;

        rgb.A = xyz.A;

        return rgb;
    }
```

On my testing application, I make a tilemap, each with it's own color, then give it a hue through HSV and cycle them so it shows the full spectrum. Then, every update it gets the hue added to so it moves through the spectrum.
[image]

However, when I convert the color to and from XYZ it shows up like this.
[image]

Here's the code in case you were interested. The `HSVtoRGB` method works as expected.

```
            Hue += HUEINCREASE;
            RGBColor c = ColorMath.HSVtoRGB(Hue, 1, 1, 1);

            //Convert to XYZ and back
            XYZColor xyz = ColorMath.RGBtoXYZ(c);
            c = ColorMath.XYZtoRGB(xyz);

            Render.Color = c;
```

Both XYZColor and RGBColor are structs. RGBColor holds floats, and if it's value is greater than 1, it wraps the color around. So if it had a red value of 1.1f, it would wrap it to .1f;

Comment: It looks to be that wrap around that you mentioned. I did the calculation for `Blue (0,0,255)` and ended up with a value that was roughly 1.0000002 in the blue channel. This would wrap around to 0.0000002 as you described and result in black (which is what your result shows). You probably need to clamp your values to the range of 0 to 1 after each calculation.

Comment: ok, I'll give clamping a try, if it works, I'll let you know so you can make it an answer and get credit :)

Comment: Works great! If you make it an answer I can except it. I'll have to be more careful about that wrap-around business. I'm thinking of making an enum that holds values for possible actions, like DoNothing, WrapAround, Clamp, etc, etc Thanks for the help!

Comment: @lukegravitt quick question, do you know what the max values for the XYZ color space is? I can't seem to find them anywhere...

Comment: I haven't a clue. This question was the first time I'd even heard of the XYZ color space (at least in that terminology).

Comment: Honestly, me neither, I needed it for a conversion to LAB and then to LCH so I can blend colors in different ways. Googling it provides much data on it, although what it actually does different is still baffling to me but, there is no mention of a max value, or the limits imposed on each color.

Comment: the limit depends on your implementation usually the max value is 1.0f or 255i (for RGB and XYZ). btw XYZ cannot be obtained from RGB 100% correctly because XYZ is nonlinear (its the average human eye response to wavelength) and RGB is only average response in only 3 distinct wavelengths...

Comment: @Spektre I found the max values, it is X = 95.0428f, Y = 100, and Z  = 108.883. Also, I found that the RGB to XYZ conversion was pretty accurate, the only issue being, if you convert it from hue to xyz to hue again and again, the color gets lighter.

Comment: look here http://www-energie.arch.ucl.ac.be/materiaux/Rapport%20final/Images%20web%20jpg/XYZ.jpg its the XYZ human eye response graph, you can covert any spectra to RGB as integration of XYZ but not back, the reverse transform obtain just ratio between 3 distinct wavelengths and that works only for some 'colors' in real. Because of our screens use the same wavelengths the transform appears working correctly (but you cannot use different screen system). Also the magnitude can be obtained from that image.

Comment: I find the conversion works pretty well, as long as you aren't converting back and forth and back and forth over and over, which causes the color to lighten a bit every time. Close enough for government work is what I say. XD

Comment: in RGBtoXYZ you forgot to make it float:
((r + 0.055)/1.055, 2.4); --> 2.4 --> 2.4f